Consulta sobre metodos en clases en java
tengo una duda que tengo hace tiempo y me gustaria que me pudieran iluminar para ver si voy por buen camino. Estoy empezando con programacion de objetos y herencia, y estoy armando una tienda en informática. la clase que estoy trabajando es PcEscritorio y la duda surge en el método "calcularPrecio" el cual ingreso por fuera de la clase varios parametros  pensando que esos parametros pueden cambiar en un futuro y puedan modificarse fácilmente. Mi duda es si esta bien lo que hago, ya que me da la sensación que complico al metodo con tantas variables. Muchas gracias!
Codigo:
package tiendainformatica;


public class PcEscritorio extends computadora {

    private String marcaGabinete;
    private boolean pantalla;

    public PcEscritorio(String marcaGabinete, boolean pantalla, String modelo, int memRam, int almacenamiento, double precio, String marca) {
        super(modelo, memRam, almacenamiento, precio, marca);
        this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
        this.pantalla = pantalla;
    }

    public String getMarcaGabinete() {
        return marcaGabinete;
    }

    public void setMarcaGabinete(String marcaGabinete) {
        this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
    }

    public boolean isPantalla() {
        return pantalla;
    }

    public void setPantalla(boolean pantalla) {
        this.pantalla = pantalla;
    }

    public double calcularPrecio(int stock, double descuento1, double precioPantalla,int cantidadStock) {
        if (pantalla) {
            precio = (precio + precioPantalla);
        }
        if (stock > cantidadStock) {

            precio = (precio - (precio * descuento1));

        }
        return precio;

    }


package tiendainformatica;

public class TiendaInformatica {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double descuento = 0.1;
        double precioPantalla = 2500.00;
        int cantidadStock=10;


        PcEscritorio compu4 = new PcEscritorio("miguel", false, "gamer", 4, 254, 2500, "generico");

        System.out.println("el precio del producto es: $" + compu4.calcularPrecio(4, descuento, precioPantalla,cantidadStock));
    }

}


bienvenido, agrega el codigo como texto, no como imagen por favor.

Hola, te invito a leer esta respuesta

El enfoque como bien han comentado varios compañeros depende de como quieras evolucionar tu programa pero, visto lo visto te doy el siguiente consejo:
En el momento que alguna entidad tiene características propias, deberías por norma general convertirla en clase (aunque sea una sola característica) ya que con el tiempo puede requerir de más atributos con la evolución del programa.
Por ejemplo, yendo a lo concreto de tu caso, un método de una clase que calcula o realiza cualquier tipo de lógica de negocio sobre una entidad no debería requerir que se le proporcionase información externa sobre otra entidad:
En el método calcularPrecio() se requiere del precio de la pantalla, igual hay que plantear que la pantalla debe ser una nueva entidad (aunque solo almacene el precio por ahora, igual con la evolución del programa se requiere mas atributos o igual no) y de esta forma no hay dependencia de información externa, por lo que puedes realizar un método bastante más limpiopara calcular el precio de un pc, digamos que de esta forma la entidad PcEscritorio tiene toda la información necesaría para operar por si mismo
y calcular su propio precio. Además, el stock no es algo que deba de preocupar a la entidad PcEscritorio, el stock parece algo mas bien propio de la entidad TiendaInformática por lo que la comprobación de stock igual debería estar en un método aparte dentro de la tienda informática:
public class Computadora {

private String modelo;
private int memRam;
private int almacenamiento;
private double precio;
private String marca;

public Computadora(String modelo, int memRam, int almacenamiento, double precio, String marca) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.memRam = memRam;
    this.almacenamiento = almacenamiento;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getModelo() {
    return modelo;
}

public void setModelo(String modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
}

public int getMemRam() {
    return memRam;
}

public void setMemRam(int memRam) {
    this.memRam = memRam;
}

public int getAlmacenamiento() {
    return almacenamiento;
}

public void setAlmacenamiento(int almacenamiento) {
    this.almacenamiento = almacenamiento;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}
}

Aqui la clase padre Computadora.
public class PcEscritorio extends Computadora {

private String marcaGabinete;
private Pantalla pantalla;

public PcEscritorio(String marcaGabinete, Pantalla pantalla, String modelo, int memRam, int almacenamiento, double precio, String marca) {
    super(modelo, memRam, almacenamiento, precio, marca);
    this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
    this.pantalla = pantalla;
}

public PcEscritorio(String marcaGabinete,String modelo, int memRam, int almacenamiento, double precio, String marca) {
    super(modelo, memRam, almacenamiento, precio, marca);
    this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
}

public String getMarcaGabinete() {
    return marcaGabinete;
}

public void setMarcaGabinete(String marcaGabinete) {
    this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
}

public Pantalla isPantalla() {
    return pantalla;
}

public void setPantalla(Pantalla pantalla) {
    this.pantalla = pantalla;
}

public double calcularPrecio() {
    return calcularPrecio(null);
}

public double calcularPrecio(Double descuento1) {

    double precio = 0.0;

    if (this.pantalla != null) {
        precio = (precio + pantalla.getPrecio());
    }

    if (descuento1 != null) {
        precio = (precio - (precio * descuento1));
    }

    return precio;

}

}
Aqui la clase PcEscritorio, como ves pantalla ha pasado de ser un boolean a ser una entidad propia, Pantalla
public class Pantalla {

private double precio;

public Pantalla(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

}
Aqui la entidad Pantalla que de momento solo almacena el precio.
public class TiendaInformatica {

static int cantidadStock = 10;

public static void main(String... args) {

    double descuento = 0.1;
    int cantidadAComprar = 4;

    if (!comprobarExistencias(cantidadAComprar)) {
        System.out.println("No hay existencias para comprar " + cantidadAComprar + " computadoras");
        return;
    }

    PcEscritorio compu4 = new PcEscritorio("miguel", new Pantalla(2500.00), "gamer", 4, 254, 2500, "generico");

    System.out.println("el precio del producto es: $" + compu4.calcularPrecio(descuento));
}

public static Boolean comprobarExistencias(int cantidadAComprobar) {

    Boolean haySuficiente = cantidadStock >= cantidadAComprobar;

    if (haySuficiente) {
        cantidadStock = cantidadStock - cantidadAComprobar;
    }

    return haySuficiente;
}

}
Y aqui la clase main a la que se le ha añadido un control de stock.
De esta forma podrás llamar a calcularPrecio(); sin argumentos en caso de que no lleve descuentos gracias a la sobrecarga de métodos o calcularPrecio(descuento) en caso de que tenga descuento, cada entidad se encarga de lo suyo y no necesita información exterior adicional como que un PcEscritorio tenga conocimientos sobre el stock cuando es cosa de la tienda o que desconozca el precio de la pantalla cuando es algo propio. Del mismo modo, en vez de crear una entidad Pantalla podrías trabajar sin más con precioPantalla en PcEscritorio como Double (en vez de tipo primitivo double) y si precioPantalla es null no lleva pantalla, en caso contrario si lleva pantalla
public class PcEscritorio extends Computadora {

private String marcaGabinete;
private Double pantalla;

public PcEscritorio(String marcaGabinete, Double pantalla, String modelo, int memRam, int almacenamiento, double precio, String marca) {
    super(modelo, memRam, almacenamiento, precio, marca);
    this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
    this.pantalla = pantalla;
}

public PcEscritorio(String marcaGabinete,String modelo, int memRam, int almacenamiento, double precio, String marca) {
    super(modelo, memRam, almacenamiento, precio, marca);
    this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
}

public String getMarcaGabinete() {
    return marcaGabinete;
}

public void setMarcaGabinete(String marcaGabinete) {
    this.marcaGabinete = marcaGabinete;
}

public Double isPantalla() {
    return pantalla;
}

public void setPantalla(Double pantalla) {
    this.pantalla = pantalla;
}

public double calcularPrecio() {
    return calcularPrecio(null);
}

public double calcularPrecio(Double descuento1) {

    double precio = 0.0;

    if (this.pantalla != null) {
        precio = (precio + pantalla);
    }

    if (descuento1 != null) {
        precio = (precio - (precio * descuento1));
    }

    return precio;

}

}

Creo que deberias de modificar el enfoque, si tu enfoque es una tienda, sera muy engorroso el tener que hacer que cada producto tenga su calculo de precio, que pasara cuando tengas 100 productos distintos y tengas que hacer un cambio por ejemplo cambio en leyes por un impuesto nuevo o cualquier otra variante que pueda suceder, creo que lo mejor es enfocar la logica en algo mas generico clase producto, clase factura y clase item factura por ejemplo y que el item de factura se encarge de esa logica de calculos de precios y totales, que el producto solo tenga el precio definido y que la clase factura se encarge de los totales a cobrar, esto sera una mejor aproximacion para el proyecto que estas desarrollando

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Es un poco difícil opinar sobre tu programa, ya que estos programas se hacen muy "a medida", pero me voy a tirar a la pileta.
Primera observación (para tomar con pinzas, el que sabe que necesitas, eres tu, esto es solo una opinión), el método calcularPrecio, no solo debe ir en otra clase, sino que debe recibir como parámetro, al objeto del que se desea saber el precio, lo de pasarle tantos parámetros, puede ser muy práctico para el programador, pero para el usuario, un verdadero incordio, los parámetros deben ser modificados solo cuando es necesario, y deben poder ser invocados por el objeto.
Y hablando del objeto, no puedo saber si es una computadora comprada, o ensamblada, supongo que es comprada, si es así, solo deberías agregar otros constructores, con distintos parámetros, incluido uno que no los reciba, si no es así, yo cambiría el enfoque, crearía la clase Gabinete, la clase Memoria, etc, que te permiten mayor libertad.
Volviendo al cálculo del precio, hay un parámetro llamado cantidadStock, que no estaría teniendo mucho sentido, por momentos, pienso que es la cantidad de productos comprados, pero entonces ¿no deberías multiplicar el precio por el?, si no es, deberías ponerle un nombre que sea más descriptivo...
En resumen, no esta nada mal, pero yo siempre trato  de que las clases sean pequeñas, pocos atributos, pocos métodos, y si realmente necesito muchos, dejo en la clase solo los setters y getters, y llevo todos los métodos que dan funcionalidad a otra clase.
